# +1 to button using javascript or jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, button, increment

I want to increment a button value on a button click which I will later need to submit to my database.

I'm currently doing it like shown below but when I click the button the incremented values shows and the button text "GOAL" disappears.

How can i make it so that when the button is clicked it would change the button name to the incremented value instead of A. Taking away the buttons name or B: Having to use an input field to display the result

I would like it to display like this:

```
GOAL then GOAL    etc etc
(1)       (2)
```

the html

```
<button type="button" id ="button1" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">GOAL</button>
```

the jquery

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('#button1').html(function(i, val) { return (val*1+1) });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can just add a `span` element in this `button` and change the `span`'s content when user clicks the button.

html

```
<button type="button" id ="button1" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary">
GOAL<br>(<span>1</span>)
</button>
```

jQuery:

```
$('#button1').click(function() {
    $('#button1 span').html(function(i, val) { return (val*1+1) });
});
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't quite undertand you but if you want to keep *goal* string and increment clicks after it here's a solution:

```
(function(){
  var goalStr = 'GOAL ';
  // You can read it from the button as well
  // var goalStr  = $('#button1').text();
  var i = 0;
  $('#button1').click(function() {
    i++;
    $(this).text(goalStr+i);
  });
})();
```

Answer (score 2):

I wrote something like this:

```
let v;
let firstTime = true;
$('#button1').click(function() 
{
    if (firstTime) {
        v = 1;
        firstTime = false;
    } else {
        v++;
    }
    $(this).html(v);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

simply add text to the HTML of the button like this

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>

  <body>

    <button type="button" id ="button1" class="btn btn-lg btn-primary"><span class="btn-text">GOAL</span><div class="btn-value"></div></button>

    <script>
        $('#button1').click(function() {
            $('#button1').find('.btn-value').html(function(i, val) {return (val*1+1); });
        });
    </script>

  </body>
</html>
```